# MongoDB nested aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, pymongo

So, I have two collections **User** and **Book**, and I want to aggregate them to receive an output (shown at the end of the post) for a specific User ID.

below are the collections:

**User**

Each document contains `User ID`, `Name` of the User and an array containing ID of a document from Book collection and a Boolean property `read`.

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('adfa2sd5'),
    name: "Mia",
    books: [
        {
            bid: "154854",
            read: true
        },
        {
            bid: "5475786",
            read: false
        }
    ]

  },

  {
    _id: ObjectId('uai5as5a'),
    name: "Jack",
    books: [
        {
            bid: "5475786",
            read: true
        }
    ]

  }
]
```

**Book**

Each document possesses a `book ID` and `name` of the book.

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('154854'),
    name: "The Great Gatsby"
  },

  {
    _id: ObjectId('5475786'),
    name: "Frankenstein"
  },
]
```

Output:

The output contains the `User ID`, along an array `book_list` which contains detail of each book (id, name) from the documents of *Book* collection based on the `books.bid` from User document and `read` field which was along `books.bid`.

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('adfa2sd5'),
    book_list: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId('154854'),
            name: "The Great Gatsby",
            read: true
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId('5475786'),
            name: "Frankenstein",
            read: false
        }
    ]

  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`"$lookup"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)?

Comment: I did try using it, but it doesn't add the `book_list.read` in the output as shown above. It probably needs a complex query which I couldn't figure out. @rickhg12hs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": ObjectId("fedcba9876543210fedcba98")
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "books",
      "localField": "books.bid",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "bookList"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "books": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$books",
          "as": "book",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$book",
              {
                "name": {
                  "$getField": {
                    "field": "name",
                    "input": {
                      "$first": {
                        "$filter": {
                          "input": "$bookList",
                          "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this._id", "$$book.bid"]}
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unset": ["bookList", "name"]}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bdpi3owaYlN).